# Eclipse - Python

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

My config -  Win 7 - Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) 
Build id: 20140612-0600
Python 3.5

I have an import statement

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Eclipse says unresolved import: urlparse

I have checked in Eclipse
Window/preferences/PyDev/Interpreters/Python Interpreters/
 Python 3.5
and I have put the path to the urllib folder

I have restarted my computer and reopen Eclipse.

This problem still exists.

Please some one advise.

Thanks you

Comment: Your interpreter or PYTHONPATH has not been setup properly.

Comment: You may want to consider learning about how Python finds and resolves modules. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the pythonpath.  urlparse is contained in parse.py which is in the Lib folder, which is in my pythonpath - but yet Eclipse doesnt find it. Run the code in IDLE and it finds urlparse and works as expected

Comment: I finally got it sorted, I removed the path to Lib, rebooted, and added it again.